# Avoiding TSQL Data-conversion errors

Tags: t-sql, sybase, data-conversion

I think this is best asked in the form of a simple example. The following chunk of SQL causes a *"DB-Library Error:20049 Severity:4 Message:Data-conversion resulted in overflow"* message, but how come?

```
declare @a numeric(18,6), @b numeric(18,6), @c numeric(18,6)
select @a = 1.000000, @b = 1.000000, @c = 1.000000
select @a/(@b/@c)
go
```

How is this any different to:

```
select 1.000000/(1.000000/1.000000)
go
```

which works fine?

Comment: I don't know if this adds anything, but what happens with select (@a*@b)/@c which is algebraically identical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same problem the last time I tried to use Sybase (many years ago). Coming from a SQL Server mindset, I didn't realize that Sybase would attempt to coerce the decimals out -- which, mathematically, is what it **should** do. :)

From the [Sybase manual](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/sqlug/@Generic__BookTextView/34781;pt=35709):

> Arithmetic overflow errors occur when
>   the new type has too few decimal
>   places to accommodate the results.

And further down:

> During implicit conversions to numeric
>   or decimal types, loss of scale
>   generates a scale error. Use the
>   arithabort numeric_truncation option
>   to determine how serious such an error
>   is considered. The default setting,
>   arithabort numeric_truncation on,
>   aborts the statement that causes the
>   error but continues to process other
>   statements in the transaction or
>   batch. If you set arithabort
>   numeric_truncation off, Adaptive
>   Server truncates the query results and
>   continues processing.

So *assuming that the loss of precision is acceptable in your scenario*, you probably want the following at the beginning of your transaction:

```
SET ARITHABORT NUMERIC_TRUNCATION OFF
```

And then at the end of your transaction:

```
SET ARITHABORT NUMERIC_TRUNCATION ON
```

This is what solved it for me those many years ago ...

Answer (score 1):

This is just speculation, but could it be that the DBMS doesn't look at the dynamic value of your variables but only the potential values?  Thus, a six-decimal numeric divided by a six-decimal numeric could result in a twelve-decimal numeric; in the literal division, the DBMS knows there is no overflow.  Still not sure why the DBMS would care, though--shouldn't it return the result of two six-decimal divisions as up to a 18-decimal numeric?

Answer (score 1):

Because you have declared the variables in the first example the result is expected to be of the same declaration (i.e. numeric (18,6)) but it is not.

I have to say that the first one worked in SQL2005 though (returned 1.000000 [The same declared type]) while the second one returned (1.00000000000000000000000 [A total different declaration]).

Answer (score 0):

Not directly related, but could possibly save someone some time with the Arithmetic overflow errors using Sybase ASE (12.5.0.3).

I was setting a few default values in a temporary table which I intended to update later on, and stumbled on to an Arithmetic overflow error.

```
declare @a numeric(6,3)

select 0.000 as thenumber into #test --indirect declare

select @a = ( select thenumber + 100 from #test )

update #test set thenumber = @a

select * from #test
```

Shows the error:

```
Arithmetic overflow during implicit conversion of NUMERIC value '100.000' to a NUMERIC field .
```

Which in my head should work, but doesn't as the 'thenumber' column wasn't  declared ( or indirectly declared as decimal(4,3) ). So you would have to indirectly declare the temp table column with scale and precision to the format you want, as in my case was 000.000.

```
select 000.000 as thenumber into #test --this solved it
```

Hopefully that saves someone some time :)